# Xcode 6.1 console input/output

Tags: objective-c, xcode, console, console-application

Ok so I've tried both ignoring and Googling this without luck.

I'm writing a Objective-C Console Application and have something like this running:

```
#import <readline/readline.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
      char *input = readline("Input data: ");
      // do stuff with input
  }
  return 0;
}
```

So the problem I'm having is that when I type input into the Xcode console (showing 'Target Output') it shows every given character twice.

```
Input Data: /*TestString becomes*/ TTeessttSSttrriinngg
```

For some reason it reads back everything I input which is really starting to bug me out...
I've searched for some setting but come up dry...
Should perhaps mention that I haven't been using Xcode much before, this is my first course so might be something simple I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok after another Google session I found out that this is working as intended and that the program works well in Terminal.

Very annoying tho...